# Is there a way to optimize an auto-complete keyword query in mongo

Tags: mongodb

I am creating an autocomplete service against my mongo db posts collection where a user can start to type the title of a post.  It should return all posts with that keyword in the title and sort by a field called 'total'.

I have a field called "lower" that is a lowercase version of the title field we want to search, and that has an index set on it.  Since I am looking for any keyword match, I am doing a regex search against lowerCaseTitle for words that appear anywhere in the title, not just in the beginning.

I looked at the execution plan and it looks like does a scan through every item (the full posts collection has 10061 items).  I tried hinting at both the "lower_1" index and the "total_-1" index and they seem similar, but the total index seems better with a lower nscanned number if I set a limit number of 50 to the query.  Is there anything I can do to optimize?  I can't think of anything simple off the top of the head for this kind of full-text searching.

```
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor lower_1",
    "nscanned" : 10061,
    "nscannedObjects" : 2,
    "n" : 2,
    "scanAndOrder" : true,
    "millis" : 154,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "lower" : [
            [
                "",
                {

                }
            ]
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> > I am doing a regex search against lowerCaseTitle for words that appear anywhere in the title, not just in the beginning.

From the [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions):

> > For simple prefix queries (also called rooted regexps) like `/^prefix/,` the database will use an index when available and appropriate (much like most SQL databases that use indexes for a `LIKE 'prefix%'` expression). This only works if you don't have `i` (case-insensitivity) in the flags.

In other words, no, MongoDB does not support searching substrings in a fast manner.

However, you can do the following to support words starting with a given string:

```
BlogPost { 
  Title : "This is furiously interesting post"
  TitleSearch : [ "this", "is", "furiously", "interesting", "post" ]
}
```

Now, with `TitleSearch` indexed and using a rooted regex, a search for `'inter'` would return the sample, also for `'furious'`, but not for `'eresting'`.

Comment: I guess I would do an && match to match on a multiple word search... is there suggestion on how to make exact matches show up first?  So that "This is furiously" would show the above example first before say "furiously this is" and "is this furiously" ?

Comment: I don't think so. If you need higher fidelity, I guess it's best to use a search-specialized solution such as SolR which also supports stemming, faceted search, result ranking and many more search-related features.